# Automatically shutdown of mac application possible?

Tags: install4j

for windows there exists a task to shutdown a running application before update the application itself. Is there a solution for mac os? I need to check whether an instance of the installed application is running and kil this process before starting the update process of install4j.

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 5.x this is not possible. The action will be modified to work on Mac OS X as well for install4j 6.

Comment: So the only way for install4j 5 is to create a shell script for searching and killing for application process and run it with the _"Run script"_ task?